# Putting minted code inside TikZ node causes missing \item error

Tags: tikz-pgf, minted, tikz-node

When I put some `minted` code inside a basic rectangular TikZ `node` as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{minted}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[]
\node[rectangle](a){
\begin{minted}{perl6}
say grep {$_ %% 3},[...] +<< prompt.split(" ").reverse
\end{minted}
};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The `lualatex --shell-escape` compiler gives the following error:

```
! LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.1 \begin{Verbatim}[commandchars=\\\{\}]
```

When I searched for this particular problem, I've noticed that it's not even asked. Do I miss something  very obvious, have no idea.

How to put a `minted` code inside a `TikZ` `node` ?

System: TeXLive 2020 on Mac OS X

Comment: Ther errors goes away if you install a `text width` but that will add vertical space at the top. Similarly, a `minipage` (almost the same) helps, too, and doesn't add vertical space. You will need to set a width, though.

Comment: If you only need one line without setting a width you are better off using `\mintinline`: `\node{\mintinline{perl6}!say grep {$_ %% 3},[...] +<< prompt.split(" ").reverse!};`

Comment: (not all solutions are applicable, but the basic principle -- i.e. horizontal versus vertical mode -- is the same throughout, and most solutions applies.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can wrap it in a `minipage` like this

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{minted}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node {
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
\begin{minted}{perl6}
say grep {$_ %% 3},[...] +<< prompt.split(" ").reverse
\end{minted}
\end{minipage}
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: One line of syntax highlighted code]